# Getting a TABLE_NAME by testing its values

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the name of the unknown TABLE_NAME by testing its values (i.e its COLUMN_NAME and the COLUMN_NAME's value) but feel stuck in the rock by the knowledge at my disposal at the moment.

Below is the bad sql query I could create at the moment:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "work" AND 
   (SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME.email = "obston@gmail.com") = true;
```

Any help would be appreciated tremendously... thanks in advance

Comment: columns typically don't have email address

Comment: you want the column to be named email and there to exist a specific value in the column?

Comment: I created a column called email that I use to store email address of my clients, is that wrong of me?@Hogan

Comment: no it is very good of you.  See my answer.

Comment: No I have the column created/named already but want to get the table_name by referring to a particular column called email with the field value of the email

Comment: Yes I have understood this question but this is not the way SQL works really.  You probably have done something very wrong if you have made so many tables this is the only way to find them.  How many tables do you have with a column called email?

Comment: Like 5 tables out of 5 tables@Hogan...

Answer (score 1):

So you asked for my suggestion and here it is....

You should avoid dynamic sql at all costs when working with SQL -- it is a bad idea.  In this case you have five tables with a column and you want an easy way to search all of them and find the name.  If I had this requirement I would do the following -- create a view that normalizes (or de-normalizes, depending on your data model details) and then do a select from that.

It would look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ALL_EMAIL (
   TABLENAME VARCHAR(100),
   EMAIL     VARCHAR(100)
)
AS 

  SELECT 'Table1', Email 
  FROM Table1
  UNION ALL

  SELECT 'Table2', Email 
  FROM Table2
  UNION ALL

  SELECT 'Table3', Email 
  FROM Table3
  UNION ALL

  SELECT 'Table4', Email 
  FROM Table4
  UNION ALL

  SELECT 'Table5', Email 
  FROM Table5
```

Now that you have this view you can just do this:

```
  SELECT TABLENAME
  FROM ALL_EMAIL
  WHERE EMAIL = 'obston@gmail.com'
```

This is by far the "best practice" way to solve this problem.

---

**prior answer**

I think you want this

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM information_schema.column 
WHERE ucase(COLUMN_NAME) = 'EMAIL'
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'work'
```

lets say this returns the result "sam" then you can test the values like this

```
SELECT *
FROM sam
WHERE email = 'obston@gmail.com'
```

Comment: Thanks... but what is ucase?

Comment: it might be UPPER depending on the SQL platform you are using -- it makes a string upper case.

Comment: Ok, so I just have to break that bad query of mine into pieces... thank you again.

Comment: But presumably the answer to your question is going to involve dynamic SQL after the point you discover the table name.

Comment: But is there any way I could execute those actions using just one query?@Hogan

Comment: @keldimkpa - you can use dynamic SQL -- you need to tell us what platform you are using since it is different on every platform to answer that question.

Comment: I'm using MySQL@Hogan

Comment: I just want to get to a particular table name with a particular column name as email and a particular column value as obston@gmail.com given that I have many tables with the same column name as email but different values@Hogan

Comment: @keldimkpa -- you have said this many times.  Why can't you use dynamic sql?

Comment: Okay, I will check that out but any help would be appreciated@Hogan

Comment: @keldimkpa -- ok there you go my final thoughts on the matter are in the answer.